# Searching for plain new line in the first line

Tags: c#, regex, newline

I want to check if the first line in a text file is just plain new line in Linux format, I created this piece of code

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines(csvFileName).First();

string pat = @"\n";
Regex r = new Regex(pat);
bool check = r.IsMatch(line1);

if (check == true)
{

}
```

I have a file which starts with plain LF newline at the beginning but the result is always FALSE. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think ReadLines strips the newline char(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadLines` interprets `\n` characters as line breaks. They are never added to elements of the `IEnumerable` that you get back. What you would get is an empty line:

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines(csvFileName).FirstOrDefault();
if (line1 != null && line1.Length == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("First line is empty.");
}
```

You can check that the line is empty. However, you would get an empty line for any line separator acceptable on your system, not only for `'\n'`.